# cannot retrieve data from angular http

Tags: mongodb, angular, rest, mean-stack, angular-http

I'm trying to retrieve data from a collection in my mongodb using http module using the code below,

```
getPosts() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:5005/blog/getposts').map(res => {
      console.log("mapped result",res);
      res.json()
    });
  }
```

It fails everytime with a response

```
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.webpackJsonp.../../../http/@angular/http.es5.js.Body.json (http.es5.js:797)
    at MapSubscriber.project (auth.service.ts:45)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:79)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1226)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
```

but when I try it with postman, I'm getting the expected result which is this,
[image]

I'm returning the response from the service and subscribing its data from a component like this,

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.getPosts().subscribe(data => {
      this.value = data.posts;
      console.log("blog component",this.value)
    },err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: try this one console.log("blog component",this.value | json);

Comment: Are you using `Http` module or `HttpClient` module?

Comment: I'm using http module. Other calls are working fine but just this :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the response in `map` and subscribe to it to get the final `JSON` response

Updated code would look like this-

```
getPosts() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:5005/blog/getposts')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
        //console.log(data);
    });
}
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: I'm already subscribing the result from a component. I have updated my question, please check

Comment: You are subscribing it in the component which is correct. What you are missing is to subscribe the mapped response from http get call in the auth service. The service is not returning a subscription and hence the error. Let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Can you post the updated code (auth service) here? It should work.

Comment: I tried copying the exact code you have in your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try returning inside the `.map()`

```js
getPosts() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:5005/blog/getposts').map(res => {
      console.log("mapped result",res);
      return res.json()
    });
  }
}
```

or drop the brackets (this gives you an implied return),

```js
getPosts() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:5005/blog/getposts')
      .map(res => res.json() );
  }
}
```