# getting unusual response from http module angular

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express, mean

I'm trying to fetch data from an api call with the following code,

**auth.service.ts**,

```
getPosts() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:5005/blog/getposts').map(res =>  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res || null)) );
}
```

**component.ts**,

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.getPosts().subscribe(data => {
      this.value = data;
      console.log("blog component",this.value)
    },err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
```

but i'm getting a response like this,

[image]

tried calling the api through postman which gives the following expected result,

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Are you using the HTTPClientModule? If so you don't need to map the output. Angular does it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm using HttpModule not HttpClientModule

Comment: If you're on Angular 4+, you should use the HttpClientModule. Is there any chance you can switch? I would bet it has to do with how you are mapping the response.

Comment: You should consider adding to your first question [cannot retrieve data from angular http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48106186/cannot-retrieve-data-from-angular-http) rather than asking again, after all you are getting the same answers!

Comment: in my previous question i got unexpected token error, i was able to resolve by replacing res.json() with JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res || null)). so i thought posting it as another new question makes sense

Comment: @joshrathhke tried using httpclient module, it gives me a response like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y4zpYF06hXAOPJXfuT9i-GTd5WAZYpk_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is an actual duplicate from your previous question, the underlying problem is completely the same, the "solution" you have tried just removes the error, but doesn't solve the issue. Please try and reproduce the issue in a StackBlitz with some dummy code and see if you can reproduce it :)

Comment: it is returning my index.html file if I try sending the response as text. I doubt if this line in my express server is causing the issue => app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'))
}); :(

Answer (score 0):

I think your map statement is causing issues. It's way more complicated than it needs to be. You could switch to the new `HttpClientModule` which maps the response for you.

```js
getPosts(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:5005/blog/getposts');
}
```

Alternatively you could try simplifying your map statement.

```js
getPosts(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:5005/blog/getposts').map(res =>  res.json() );
}
```

Comment: if i try mapping my response as json im getting an error like this "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"